# I want to filter array of object with respect to date javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, reduce

**This is the current array of object I have**,
I want to transform this first array of object into the second one given below:
I tried using reduce.
I want that, for the particular date I should have all the topic as key and count as value :

````
```const myObj = [
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Technical_support/Installation",
    "count": "2"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "pricing",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Product/sales enquiry",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Service",
    "count": "4"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "others",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Product/sales enquiry",
    "count": "5"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Service",
    "count": "28"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Billing/order",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Service",
    "count": "11"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "others",
    "count": "5"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Technical_support/Installation",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "pricing",
    "count": "6"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "pricing",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "offer",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Product/sales enquiry",
    "count": "4"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "offer",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "others",
    "count": "15"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Technical_support/Installation",
    "count": "10"
}
]
````

**I want to achive this result I want to transform this first array of object into the second one given below: I tried using reduce. I want that, for the particular date I should have all the topic as key and count as value :**

````
  {
    date: "2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "Billing / Order": 20,
    Delivery: 30,
    "Product/sales enquiry": 40,
    Service: 24,
    "Technical_support/Installation": 24,
    pricing: 24,
    Usability: 24,
    offer: 24,
    others: 24,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "Billing/order": 30,
    Delivery: 10,
    "Product/sales enquiry": 30,
    Service: 24,
    "Technical_support/Installation": 14,
    pricing: 54,
    Usability: 24,
    offer: 24,
    others: 24,
  },
  {
    date: "2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "Billing/order": 40,
    Delivery: 30,
    "Product/sales enquiry": 40,
    Service: 54,
    "Technical_support/Installation": 24,
    pricing: 14,
    Usability: 24,
    offer: 14,
    others: 34,
  },
];```
````

Comment: Can you provide an expected data based on the output of `myObj`?

Comment: @lucumt I'm getting above arr of object from api, I want to transform that data to below array of object don't look at the date's they are different, but I want that for the particular date whatever the topics are, they must be present in one object, same for other dates

Comment: Hey,the data in below array is not come from `myObj`,especially the `date` value is not matched

Comment: @lucumt don't look for the date, they are just for the instance, I don't want exact same answer, they are just for keeping in mind, did you got the point, there are three dates so like for example, for date 10 I want all the topics, I transform the format of the date using moment, you can see the below dates format same as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question,you can try below code snippet.

Note: the `date` format is not translated as your posted

```js
const myObj = [
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Technical_support/Installation",
    "count": "2"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "pricing",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Product/sales enquiry",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Service",
    "count": "4"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "others",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Product/sales enquiry",
    "count": "5"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Service",
    "count": "28"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Billing/order",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Service",
    "count": "11"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "others",
    "count": "5"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Technical_support/Installation",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "pricing",
    "count": "6"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "pricing",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "offer",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Product/sales enquiry",
    "count": "4"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "offer",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "others",
    "count": "15"
},
{
    "created_at": "2022-06-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "topic": "Technical_support/Installation",
    "count": "10"
}
]

let result = myObj.reduce((a,v) =>{
  let obj = a.find(i => i.date == v.created_at)
  if(obj){
    obj[v.topic] = v.count
   }else{
     obj = {'date':v.created_at,[v.tpoic]:v.count}
     a.push(obj)
   }
   return a
},[])
console.log(result)
```